# How associated JStack tid and Thread.getId

Tags: java, jstack

Jstack output contains tid (thread id). I belive that tid correcponds the hex value of Thread.getId(). But it is not so. I tested this with a concrete example and got different values.
I'm interested in how tid is formed. How can I find the thread in jstack by value of Thread.getId()?

Example:

```
Thread.getId() = 64
in Jstack: tid=0x00007fb368001800 nid=0x1b99
```

Comment: Can you show us the example you tried? [See the SO tour page.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: the jstack tid is the process id in hexadecimal.  There is no guaranteed way to tie the two.